# localhost doesn't work on Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite

I have just today upgraded to Yosemite. I've not had a mac long. But with the update my localhost doesn't work. Chrome returns This webpage is not available. I've tried

`sudo apachectl start` to try and get it back but no luck. I'm a new mac user and haven't had to undergo an OS update, so not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem here was the httpd.conf file and this line

`Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf`

Where it tried to load the osx version of PHP I had. I needed to change it to my PHP version

`Include /private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf`

Permissions seem to be an issue now however.

Answer (score 4):

I've stolen the following from
https://github.com/liip/php-osx/issues/75 and http://php-osx.liip.ch/#uninstall

## 1. reinstall PHP

homebrew helps with this

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew uninstall --force php54
brew unlink php54
brew uninstall --force php55
brew unlink php55
rm -rf /usr/local/php5*
brew install php55
```

## 2. where is **libphp5.so**?

please comment out the existing 'LoadModule php5_module' in /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf and add this

```
LoadModule php5_module /path/to/lib/libphp5.so
```

## 3. delete **+php-osx.conf** and **+entropy-php.conf**

delete the files

```
+php-osx.conf
+entropy-php.conf
```

in

```
/etc/apache2/other
```

## 4. testing if everything works

try to start apache with

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Comment: what is the purpose of delete the apache php files??

Comment: @raoulsson, try running ```brew tap homebrew/php```

Answer (score 3):

did you try

```
apachectl configtest
```

to see if it really is running?

I've just found this:

http://macosx.com/threads/apache-wont-start-up.299851/

-> ***summary***

'Apache couldn't find a certain log file'

```
cd /private/var/log
sudo mkdir apache2
```

Comment: I got an error: Syntax error on line 527 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _unixd_config\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so\n  Expected in: /usr/sbin/httpd\n in /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so

Answer (score 2):

I'm just upgraded my mac into yosemite, and boom my apache isn't working. i follow the instruction from [here](http://encore254.blogspot.com/2014/07/apache-issue-after-installing-os-x.html), and my localhost is back to normal again, here the simple steps i did.

1. Open your **httpd.conf** located on **/etc/apache2**, please open with sudo like `sudo vi httpd.conf` (i'm using vim to open  the file, for most simple steps)
2. Find the line with this value `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`, you will found it marked with `#`, so delete the hash (`#`) and save the file by press `ESC` => type `:wq` (command for *write* and *quit*)
   [image: Step where finding the line]
3. Restart your apache by using command `sudo apachectl restart`
4. See your `localhost` on browser
   [image: Localhost works]

   ***tips:**

   For fast on searching you can press `ESC` and then `/`, and type `php5_module` => `ENTER`

   You can also remove the mark (hash) fot these line, if you need to enable `rewrite_module` to activate `mod_rewrite` and `vhost_alias_module` for `virtual-host` on your machine.

   ***warning**

   If your **MOD_REWRITE** still doesn't work, in order to use `.htaccess` try to check this.

   Find the section and change
   `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution in Jan 2016 for El Capitan

None of the other answers worked for me.

1. run sudo apachectl configtest

I got an error:

AH00526: Syntax error on line 20 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf: Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

That lead me to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211015/el-capitan-apache-error-message-ah00526 and the solution

Edit the file /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf to remove this part:

```
#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
  LockFile "/private/var/log/apache2/accept.lock"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I commented that out, rolled back all the other changes(except brew update/upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

I just did:

```html
brew update
brew upgrade
```

and

```html
sudo apachectl restart
```

..."It works!"

Comment: This solution will only work if the user is using brew.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too after upgrading Yosemite recently. Neither localhost nor 127.0.0.1 would resolve. Apparently Yosemite activated or reconfigured a Firewall (System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall [tab]).

I resolved the issue by accessing the Firewall Options and unchecking the box labelled 'Block all incoming connections'. Probably more importantly - that caused the 'Enable stealth mode' option below it to be switched off. That, stealth mode, was likely the culprit.

After saving above changes localhost & 127.0.0.1 worked fine for me again.